# Is $ f(x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{(x-y)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2} \\0\end{cases}$ continuos?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}, \begin {pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \mapsto  \begin{cases} \frac{(x-y)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2} &\text{if $(x,y) \neq (1,1)$ }\\0&\text{if $ (x,y)=(1,1)$}\end{cases}$

In which points is $f$ continuously?

I tried to prove that $f$ is not continuous using a couple of sequences, and tried to show that $f$ is continuous by assessing it above, but both failed...

Comment: It may be easier to see if you translate it, use the coordinates $\xi = x-1$ and $\eta = y-1$. Then maybe polar coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use polor coordinate centered at $(1,1)$
$$x=1+r\cos\theta, y=1+r\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}=\frac{r^2(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2}{r^2}=(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2$$, the value when $r \rightarrow 0$ depends on $\theta$(direction) therefore does not exist and the function is not continuous.

Comment: Elegant answer!

Answer (score 4):

$$\ \frac{(x-y)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}=\frac{[(x-1)-(y-1)]^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}$$

Now setting $\ x-1=t, y-1=s$, you get:

$$\lim_{(t,s)\to(0,0)}\frac{(t-s)^2}{t^2+s^2}$$

It is easy to show that this limit does not exist, so the function is not continuous in (1,1)

Comment: This was also one of my ideas, but i failed to show that $\lim_{(t,s)\to(0,0)}\frac{(t-s)^2}{t^2+s^2}$ does not exist. How to see this?

Comment: Choose a line $t = ks$ for some $k$. The limit is contingent on the choice of $k$.